# Using tinytest to test Meteor client while the server is running

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to test the Meteor client while the server is running using tinytest? Here's my example testing the client only:

```
Tinytest.add("Add object to a collection", function(test) {
  var people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
  people.insert({"name": "Andrew"}, function(error, id) {
    test.isNull(error);
  });
});
```

For a fraction of a second this passes, but then it goes into the state of "waiting". I'm also positive that error is not null.

```
Meteor.Error {error: 404, reason: "Method not found", details: undefined}
```

I know this is happening because their is no server for the client to communicate with. When I try to run this test on the server and client, I continue to get the same issue with the client. Is there a way to test the client while the server is running?

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Have you tried `new Meteor.Collection` with no argument (a stub)?

Comment: @Rahul no I did not try that. I think this makes sense, as I'm not really wanting to test the communication/sync between the client and server, but I do want collections to work in client and server as expected. After making the collection name null, all is good. Do you want to write this as an answer (suggest using a stub)? Thank you!

Comment: Just added it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `new Meteor.Collection` with no argument to create a stub collection that doesn't require the server. See [the docs on Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection):

> If you pass null as the name, then you're creating a local collection. It's not synchronized anywhere; it's just a local scratchpad that supports Mongo-style find, insert, update, and remove operations.

Answer (score 5):

This is an async test, so you'll have to use `addAsync`.

```
Tinytest.addAsync("Add object to a collection", function(test, next) {
  var people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
  people.insert({"name": "Andrew"}, function(error, id) {
    test.isNull(error);
    next();
  });
});
```

Note the next argument which signals that you are done in the callback.

Comment: Am I supposed to run this on the client and server? Either way, I've tried 'client', 'server', and ['client', 'server']. All options produced the same "waiting" state.

Comment: This is the incorrect way to use `addAsync`. I have fixed it for you.