# How to use tinytest with publish/subscribe?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, meteor

Tinytest is fairly undocumented at this point, but it looks like a nice lightweight framework to use. I have a package that depends on some publish/subscribe data and a bit stymied on how to use this. I can't seem to subscribe to a user.

Do i need to guarantee the server block runs first, such that the publish blocks are available to be subscribed to?

I also made sure my package under test included the various required other/auth packages.

```
Package.on_test(function (api) {
    api.use([
        'accounts-ui',
        'accounts-facebook', ...
```

I was hoping to find some examples in [LiveData test suite](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/livedata_server_tests.js) or even the [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/test/both/route_controller.js) test suite, but haven't turned anything up yet. FWIW i've reviewed other links on testing with meteor, and Laika and RTD [RTD](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-rtd-example-project) look a bit overkill for now.

Pointers appreciated, how to get a basic sample like below working.

```
if Meteor.isServer
    Tinytest.add "Chatbot data", (test) ->
        test.equal 1, 1, "server tests running"

        userdata = {
            email: "c@c.com"
            profile:
                nickname: "chaka"
                name: "chaka"
                icon: "/images/bots/chaka/icon/50.png"
        }

        Meteor.users.insert(userdata)
        check = Meteor.users.findOne()
        test.isNotNull check, "can't create user"
        console.log("userCheck", check) # ok
        Meteor.publish 'allUsers', ->
            return Meteor.users.find()


if Meteor.isClient
    Tinytest.add "Chatbot create", (test) ->

        Meteor.subscribe("allUsers")
        user = Meteor.users.findOne()
        if (user == undefined)
            test.fail("cant find user:", user)
```

edit: [this guidance on asycn tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985684/using-tinytest-to-test-meteor-client-while-the-server-is-running) seems to be very related.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if your method subscribes with the proper find selector I would spy Meteor.users.find() and check if that is called with the right arguments.

```
var actualFind = Meteor.users.find, receivedArguments;
Meteor.users.find = function () {
    receivedArguments = arguments;
    actualFind.apply(actualFind, arguments);
}
```

Then do tests on receivedArguments.

Testing subscribe/publish itself is something the meteor team should do.

You should only ever write unit tests for code you've written.

Comment: oh very nice. i didn't realize you could alias JS methods that easily. presumably this depends on the "actual find" meteor method already being defined, but that can be controlled by putting this in a startup block.